# How to implement CI/CD for MVC+Angular application

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I have found many articles for implementing CI/CD for Angular application but didnt helped much.

My UI project is combination of MVC and Angular . I want to implement CI/CD for this UI project.

I'm totally confused how to implement that.

Can someone suggest.

Comment: Please add more details on what you've tried so far, and what specifically you need help with.

Comment: Is that a asp.net core project? Have you added the project in source control yet?

Comment: Project refers to .Net Framework 4.6.1 not .Net Core

Comment: Then you should use tasks like `use nuget+nuget restore+Visual Studio Build` to build your project.

Comment: Hi @chandra sekhar You can also try adding npm task to build your angular project and a Visual studio build task to build MVC project repectively, then use copy file task to move the built artifacts to its right place.

Answer (score 1):

> How to implement CI/CD for MVC+Angular application. I have found many articles for implementing CI/CD for Angular application but didnt helped much.

This's quite a broad question, generally you can use Build pipeline and Release pipeline to implement CI/CD for your project. And I assume your project targets asp.net core, so this is an question about how to do CI/CD for asp.net core web app...

1.Add to source control: Make sure you've added the project into source control. For this, I suggest you can refer to [create a new repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/creatingrepo?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio#create-a-new-repo). You can choose to push the project to Azure Devops repos by VS UI or command-line.

If you have VS installed, assuming you have the project file(.csproj) and solution file(.sln), open it in VS and click the `Add to Source Control` button in bottom right corner to add the project into source control and push it to Azure Devops Repos.

2.Use Build Pipeline:

Create a new build pipeline(classic editor is more friendly to member who's new to this) and select the source(Azure Devops Repos in Step1), then click `Continue`.

You can choose the Asp.net core template, it contains these tasks: dotnet restore(restore nuget packages)=>dotnet build(build your project)=>dotnet test(test your assembly)=>dotnet publish(publish to specific path)=>publish artifacts(publish build results for release pipeline, a "bridge" between build and release pipeline)

3.Use Release Pipeline:

About deployment for asp.net core web app, you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/azure/devops/cicd?view=aspnetcore-3.1). You should add an artifact=>choose the build pipeline.

1)In tasks tab, right-click stage1 and add deployment group job=>add `Manage IIS website task+Deploy IIS website/App` if you want to deploy it to IIS.

2)And right-click stage1=>add agent job=>add `Azure App Service Deploy` task if you want to deploy to Azure App Service.